# R: name list element by variable

Tags: r, list-manipulation

Probably been asked before and I've seen some similar questions, but I would like to name my list elements according to the name of a variable `varname` in the statements

```
m=list(list(a=1,b=2),list(a=1,b=2))
v=1:length(m)
varname="c"
m=lapply(1:length(m), function(i) modifyList(m[[i]],list(varname=v[[i]])))
```

where `m` is a nested list and `v` a vector of the same length.

Problem is this returns me with sublists that are named `varname` as opposed to `"c"`:

```
m
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 1

[[1]]$b
[1] 2

[[1]]$varname
[1] 1


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
[1] 1

[[2]]$b
[1] 2

[[2]]$varname
[1] 2
```

Probably quite trivial, but how should I solve this?

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example ! what is modifyList ?

Comment: Ha that's just a base R function to modify an existing list

Comment: Sorry made into a full example now

Comment: No because that will rename the top level, whereas I want to rename sublist $varname to $c. Also I was just wondering if it could all be done in just one line, within the lapply statement.

Comment: Do you need to add variable `c` or rename existing (a,b) to `c`?

Comment: Ha I want to add the elements in vector v and name them "c", or rather the name specified in varname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m=list(list(a=1,b=2),list(a=1,b=2))
v=1:length(m)
varname="c"
```

This will work:

```
m2=lapply(1:length(m), 
     function(i) modifyList(m[[i]],setNames(list(v[[i]]),varname)))
```

or

```
m2=mapply(function(x,y) {x[[varname]] <- y; x},m,v,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Comment: Ha that's great - many thanks!! I finally hope to get my head around these kind of things :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to comment on David Arenburg's comment above, however if you do this you can adjust it to have a vector of names.

```
m=list(list(a=1,b=2),list(a=1,b=2))
v=1:length(m)
varname=c('Var1','Var2')
names(m) <- rep(varname, length(m)/length(varname))
```

`m` now looks like this:

```
$Var1
$Var1$a
[1] 1

$Var1$b
[1] 2


$Var2
$Var2$a
[1] 1

$Var2$b
[1] 2
```

You can call the values in the list like you would a dataframe (with a `$`) like this:

`m$Var1$a` which will return `1`