# How to use variable as element name when creating list in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have

`label <- 'My val'`

and I try to create the list

```
Output <- list(
  label = pi
)
```

I get that the name of the first (only) object in the list is `"label"` but I want `"My val"`.

I understand I can do

`names(Output) <- label`

But the list is quite long and I'd rather name it in the `list` function.

Comment: check out this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386171/r-name-list-element-by-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't reference variables for names when using the `list()` function to create a list. It will just interpret any variable name as name for the entry. But after constructing the list, you can change the names:

```
label <- 'My val'
Output <- list(pi)
names(Output)=label
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `lst` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
lst(!!label := pi)
#$`My val`
#[1] 3.141593
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you, but it would've been much better if you could share a more detailed sample as I thought there might be more variable names involved:

```
label <- 'My val'

Output <- list(
  label = pi
)

Output |> 
  setNames(label)

$`My val`
[1] 3.141593
```